# Remove comments when running rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails

When I test my rails app using rspec, a bunch of long comments appear.
How can I remove them ?

```
 ActionController::RoutingError:
   No route matches [GET] "/events"
 # /Users/hadi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
 # /Users/hadi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
 # /Users/hadi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
 # /Users/hadi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
 # /Users/hadi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
 # /Users/hadi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
 # /Users/hadi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
 # /Users/hadi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:68:in `block in call'
 # /Users/hadi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:53:in `each'
 # /Users/hadi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:53:in `call'
 # /Users/hadi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-test-0.6.3/lib/rack/mock_session.rb:30:in `request'
 # /Users/hadi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-test-0.6.3/lib/rack/test.rb:244:in `process_request'
 # /Users/hadi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/rack-test-0.6.3/lib/rack/test.rb:58:in `get'
 # /Users/hadi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/capybara-2.7.1/lib/capybara/rack_test/browser.rb:61:in `process'
 # /Users/hadi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/capybara-2.7.1/lib/capybara/rack_test/browser.rb:36:in `process_and_follow_redirects'
 # /Users/hadi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/capybara-2.7.1/lib/capybara/rack_test/browser.rb:22:in `visit'
 # /Users/hadi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/capybara-2.7.1/lib/capybara/rack_test/driver.rb:43:in `visit'
 # /Users/hadi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/capybara-2.7.1/lib/capybara/session.rb:233:in `visit'
 # /Users/hadi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/capybara-2.7.1/lib/capybara/dsl.rb:52:in `block (2 levels) in <module:DSL>'
 # ./spec/features/list_movies_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: add full code @h236a

Comment: these are not comments, it is called [stacktrace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_trace), and it's there because of the exception raised (`ActionController::RoutingError`)

Answer (score 1):

That's not comments that's a stack trace, to help you resolve the problem that rspec encountered.

A stack trace shows you each nested call that was made up to the point that the error was encountered, so that you can trace back to which line in your code a command was run that led to the error.

your `spec/features/list_movies_spec.rb` on line 5 it's performed a method that at some point is tryng to do `GET /events' but you don't have such a route in your route.rb

Fix the problem, and the "comments" will disappear.

Comment: Yes I know that I'm missing a route  and `No route matches [GET] "/events"` is good enough to help understand that. What I'm looking for is to disable this stack trace every time I run a test.

Comment: The stack trace is useful particularly when you're running a full suite of tests to help identify which line is the source of the problem. It may be in this case you don't need the trace, but I'm sure you'll find other errors in future where you'll be happy to have that information.  It doesn't make sense to disable the stack trace on an error type by error type basis, since if you have no errors they don't show up anyway.